# packing image resource into nuget library and accessing it

Tags: wpf, nuget, embedded-resource, pack-uri

I have a nuget package which contains some logos which should be accessible.
The logos are located in the Resources Folder:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The logos are set up as embedded resource. I can access them with the following pack url when I add the project reference:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Dexie.Space.Net;component/Resources/dexie_medium.png"></Image>
```

this does not work when I add the nuget package instead.
I have done some research and edited the project file as such withiout success:

```
 </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\dexie_black_medium.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>Resources/dexie_black_medium.png</PackagePath>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\dexie_medium.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>Resources/dexie_medium.png</PackagePath>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\dexie_white_medium.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>Resources/dexie_white_medium.png</PackagePath>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\duck_black_medium.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>Resources/duck_black_medium.png</PackagePath>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\duck_medium.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>Resources/duck_medium.png</PackagePath>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\duck_white_medium.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>Resources/duck_white_medium.png</PackagePath>
        </EmbeddedResource>
```

so either the package path or my pack url seems incorrect to me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaQ0d.png

Comment: *Embedded Resource* is the wrong Build Action. It must be *Resource*.

Comment: but wouldnt an embedded resource be embedded into the dll whereas a resource is a file? I would like to have it embedded into the dll

Comment: That also happens with Build Action Resource. The result is a so-called *assembly resource file*.